# Auto-update html element when gpio pin goes high

Tags: javascript, php

I am designing a PWA to run on a phone and control a chicken coop. It uses pseudo LED lights to show the device state (on/off/open/closed,etc). What I have so far is rock solid. However, I want the LED to change when the gpio changes state. Specifically, I have a heater control that you tun on with a button click. In the program settings, you put an ON temperature and OFF temperature so when you turn the heat feature on the led might turn blue (meaning it is on but not running) or turn red (running). When the temperature changes to a point that the heater changes state, it does not update the LED element unless I refresh the screen. I know I can do a periodic refresh but I don't want to do that. I've basically got all the pieces of the puzzle solved except how to refresh the LED element from a javascript process that periodically runs a PHP script and reads the gpio state. Here is the code for the heater button and LED:

```
<div>                               <!-- heat control on/off button -->
  <div class=dividerBig></div>
   <input id="button3" class="buttonRow3" type="button"<?php include("initButton3.php"); ?>;/>
   <div class="divider"></div><div class="divider"></div>
   <div id="led3" <?php include("device3State.php"); ?>></div>
</div>
```

And here is the device3State.php file:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("/var/lib/cca/.heaterState.txt", "r");
$var1 = fgets($file);
fclose($file);
$var2 = exec("gpio -g read 7");   // aux on switch
if($var1 == 0){
  echo "class='led-off'";}
else if(($var1 == 1) && ($var2 == 1)){
  echo "class='led-on'";}
else if(($var1 == 1) && ($var2 == 0)){
  echo "class='led-blue'";}
```

?>

The initButton3.php toggles the button text and also runs this javascript function:

```
function heaterOnOff(){
   if(document.getElementById("button3").value==" Enable Heat Control "){
     document.getElementById("button3").value=" Disable Heat Control ";
        $.get("heaterOn.php");}
else { document.getElementById("button3").value=" Disable Heat Control ";
        $.get("heaterOff.php");}
         sleep(2000);
// only refreshes one element on page (for deluxe model)
//   $( "#led3" ).load(window.location.href + " #led3" );   
// refreshes entire page (for standard model)
         location.reload(true);                                 
     }
```

The heaterOn.php and heaterOff.php called from the javascript does the work by running a C program that turns the heater on or off. It also writes a '1' or '0' to the .heaterState.txt file: 1=on 0=off

Comment: Basically you need a php script running constantly connected to the client using websocket and send an event which would switch the led state. So in that php file you'd have a while loop which reads the heaterState.txt file and saves the currentState and compares it to the state before. If it differs send a message through the socket to the client to switch the class.

Comment: The .heaterState.txt file only denotes it is enabled or not. If it contains '0' it means the heater is turned completely off. I do think a looping javascript file polling the gpio pin through the php script would work but  how to best only update one element seems to be my issue. Is the line: $( "#led3" ).load(window.location.href + " #led3" ); anywhere near correct?

Comment: Well you could format the php to only get the actual values in JSON format. Then according to that JSON you update the corresponding html elements.

Comment: So you'd do: `$data = array(); $data['heaterState'] = $var1; $data['GPIO'] = $var2; echo json_encode($data);`

Comment: `$data` would then be readable client-side with `$.get("device3State.php", function(data, status){
    var dataObject = JSON.parse(data);
    dataObject.heaterState;//like this
    dataObject.GPIO;//like this
  });`

Comment: ok... I think that makes sense. I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Note that previous javascript snippet expects the response from `device3State.php` to be valid `JSON`. It means you can't `echo` anything else but the `JSON` there unless you reformat the javascript to handle those cases. If there's any unexpected output from the php you can do `ob_clean();` just before echoing the json to clear the output buffer completely.

Comment: You can use `var timeInMilliseconds = 1000; window.setInterval(refreshState,timeInMilliseconds);` in a script tag at the end of body element and declare `function refreshState(){$.get...}` to set up your html page with 1 second refreshes to the state.

Comment: If you need more help, I could be of more use in stackoverflow chat.